# Why would a Persisted Computed Column that is stored in a Covering Index NOT be used for Updates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-indexes

I am seeing an odd behavior in SQL Server that doesn't make any sense.  I have a PERSISTED Computed Column that is stored in a Covering Index.  However, when this computed column in the covering index needs to be referenced in order to update another column in another table, the optomizer will choose not to use it at all and instead do a Key Lookup to get the values from the clustered index.  Why?

The UPDATE statement at the very end of this demo script works as expected, but if you look closely at the execution plan for it, the update does NOT use the covering index IX_MyTable_VarcharValue1_ComputedColumn.  Instead, it will do a Key Lookup and go back to the clustered index to get VarcharValue2, even tough the ComputedColumn that needs for the update is literally already there!  In my mind PERSISTED means persisted to disk.  So why isn't it using the value when it looks at the non-clustered index the first time to get VarcharValue1?  Is this not extra work doing the Key Lookup?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (
    [ID] INT NOT NULL
    , [VarcharValue1] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    , [NotComputedColumn] VARCHAR(50) NULL
        CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ID ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyTable_VarcharValue1
    ON dbo.MyTable ([VarcharValue1] ASC);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ComputedColumnTable (
    [ID] INT NOT NULL
    , [VarcharValue1] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    , [VarcharValue2] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    , [ComputedColumn] AS [VarcharValue1] + [VarcharValue2] PERSISTED NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [PK_ComputedColumnTable]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ID ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyTable_VarcharValue1_ComputedColumn
    ON dbo.ComputedColumnTable ([VarcharValue1] ASC, [ComputedColumn] ASC);

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES(1,'e',NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES(2,'d',NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES(3,'c',NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES(4,'b',NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES(5,'a',NULL)

INSERT INTO dbo.ComputedColumnTable VALUES(1,'a','b')
INSERT INTO dbo.ComputedColumnTable VALUES(2,'b','c')
INSERT INTO dbo.ComputedColumnTable VALUES(3,'c','d')
INSERT INTO dbo.ComputedColumnTable VALUES(4,'d','e')
INSERT INTO dbo.ComputedColumnTable VALUES(5,'e','f')

SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable
SELECT * FROM dbo.ComputedColumnTable

-- uses a Key Lookup to get VarcharValue2 instead of the ComputedColumn in the covering index 
UPDATE m 
SET m.NotComputedColumn = c.ComputedColumn
FROM MyTable m
    JOIN ComputedColumnTable c
        ON m.VarcharValue1 = c.VarcharValue1
```

Edit:  Adding link for Execution Plan:  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hkk_MZ8JK

Comment: You'd be better of asking this on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ since its not a programming question.

Comment: Good call thanks, I'll post on there also.

Comment: You'll find people frown on you cross posting - better one or the other.

Comment: _if you look closely at the execution plan_ No one can look AT ALL until you post the execution plan - preferably at [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Try trace flag 176, see https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-plan/properly-persisted-computed-columns

Comment: Here's the execution plan:  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hkk_MZ8JK

Comment: @SMor Interesting: TF176 does *not* appear to work, unless I place the join in a `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1`. Is this possibly related https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4024840-fix-access-violation-occurs-when-trace-flag-176-enabled-in-sql-server-2016-e16ee2d1-5e3d-d944-b6f3-aca4abc6a886 ?

Comment: @DaleK Interesting: TF176 does *not* appear to work, unless I place the join in a `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1`. Is this possibly related https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4024840-fix-access-violation-occurs-when-trace-flag-176-enabled-in-sql-server-2016-e16ee2d1-5e3d-d944-b6f3-aca4abc6a886 ?

Answer (score 0):

The clustered index update operator modifies the clustered index pages so the optimizer decided to expand the definition of the persisted column definition.

> It can come as quite a shock to see SQL Server recomputing the
> underlying expression each time while ignoring the
> deliberately-provided stored value

[Properly Persisted Computed Columns](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-plan/properly-persisted-computed-columns)

In this case, the optimizer required the **VarcharValue2** to demand a new calculation from the compute scalar operator. When we look at the compute scalar operator it re-calculates the persisted computed column value. This situation seems in the output of the ScalarString attribute.
[image]

On the other hand, we can avoid the operator key lookup operation to eliminating the Stream Aggregate but this time optimizer will decide to perform a Clustered Index Scan on the ComputedColumnTable. Because it still requires the **VarcharValue2** column but only the optimizer changes the data access methods.

```
--Don't use this options in the production database
DBCC TRACEON (3604);
DBCC RULEOFF('GbAggToStrm')
GO
UPDATE m 
SET m.NotComputedColumn = c.ComputedColumn
FROM MyTable m
    JOIN ComputedColumnTable c
        ON m.VarcharValue1 = c.VarcharValue1
DBCC RULEON('GbAggToStrm')
```

[image]

As a result the **VarcharValue2** column requirement did not change.

**What we can do:** To resolve this situation we can add the **VarcharValue2**IX_MyTable_VarcharValue1_ComputedColumn index definition.So that, we can eliminate the key lookup operation.
[image]

Comment: Adding VarcharValue2 to the index isn't really the solution I was searching for.  This demo is just a simplified example, but my question is why doesn't it use the value of ComputedColumn from the Index when the UPDATE is literally SET m.NotComputedColumn = c.ComputedColumn?  It has to look at the index anyway to get VarcharValue1, why not just get the ComputedColumn value then?